# React-big-calendar, beaks when view changes to week, work-week, day. How to fix it?

Tags: reactjs, react-big-calendar

On the project i work now we decided to use react-big-calendar. I am supplying the events data by passing it from the parent component as a props. The data comes in format {start:"ISO date string",end:"ISO date string",title:"Event name", allDay:true/false,eventID:number, roomID:number, ownerID:number}. It was working with my dummy data (without eventID,roomID,ownerID).

So, what is actually breaking: When I chose a room/rooms, it renders all events by this room/rooms. This works in mount, and agenda view. I can navigate trough the toolbar. But when I try to change the view to week,work-week or day it has unpredictable behavior. If there is no event in the day, week, or work-week, it renders well, and navigates trough the toolbar. But if try to change it to week that got events,it is re-rendering the whole page and looses all rendered events.
How can I fix this? If anyone can help or suggest what to look for?

Comment: You should always post some code so others can see what you've tried and will gladly help

Comment: I am sorry for disturbing. I just passed the ISO Date string in to 'new Date("ISO Date String")' and It worked as a charm... That was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem recently, and it was because I had forgotten to mutate all of my event `start` and `end` values to true JavaScript `Date` objects. That requirement **is** in the documentation, I had just forgotten it. Before I had done this they would still display initially, but things like changing the view, or drag n drop/resizing, would either completely break, or be highly problematic. Once I had properly converted those `start` and `end` dates to true JS `Date` objects, all of those issues went away.